# MySQL retrieve NULL records from many to many relationship

Tags: mysql, many-to-many

I have 5 tables to store the list of records of training that people were trained based on their titles. One user can have many titles/job duties.

UPDATED: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9f752)

`titles` contains "Manager", "Lead"...

```
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| uid   | int(11) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name  | varchar(100)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

`users` in which one user can have many `titles`

```
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| uid       | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| first     | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| last      | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

`procedures` users will get trained particular `procedures` based on their `titles`

```
+----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-----------------------------+
| Field    | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra                       |
+----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-----------------------------+
| uid      | int(11) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment              |
| name     | varchar(100)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                             |
+----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-----------------------------+
```

`title_map` to allow `users` have more than one title

```
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| uid       | int(11) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| title_uid | int(11)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| user_uid  | int(11)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

`procedure_title_map` to determine what `titles` are required to be train a specific procedure

```
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| uid           | int(11) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| title_uid     | int(11)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| procedure_uid | int(11)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

And `records` to keep all records that users have been trained with required or not required procedures in `procedures` table

```
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-----------------------------+
| Field         | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra                       |
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-----------------------------+
| uid           | int(11) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment              |
| procedure_uid | int(11)          | YES  |     | NULL    |                             |
| user_uid      | int(11)          | YES  |     | NULL    |                             |
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-----------------------------+
```

My question is how do I get this list:

```
+----------+-------------+----------+---------------+-------------------------+
| user_uid | record_uid  | required | procedure_uid | training_result         |
+----------+-------------+----------+---------------+-------------------------+
|     1023 |        NULL | Y        |           285 | N (Needed Training)     |
|     1131 |        234  | Y        |           285 | T                       |
|     1175 |        424  | N        |           285 | T (Trained)             |
|      323 |        NULL | N        |           285 | NULL (No Need Training) |
|     1077 |        NULL | Y        |           285 | N                       |
+----------+-------------+----------+---------------+-------------------------+
```

Comment: could you replace tables of table columns with `CREATE TABLE` statements for each? or even better provide an sqlfiddle

Comment: Updated question! Thank you!

Comment: and.... some inserts of sample data into fiddle please?